# How to view OpenCV Build Information

Tags: opencv

I've already installed OpenCV from the [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/).
 How can I get information about what settings were used to build it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[getBuildInformation()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#const%20std%3a%3astring&%20getBuildInformation%28%29) returns a string with

> cmake output including version control system revision, compiler version, compiler flags, enabled modules and third party libraries, etc. Output format depends on target architecture.